# Can't understand activation function

Tags: neural-networks

I have been trying to learn neural networks from scratch
(in Python). Wherever they talk about neural networks, I don't get the meaning of activation of a neuron, and need to understand the basic meaning of activation. Is it like activated - non activated boolean?

The definition of bias says it helps to compensate the activation of the neuron. Then do we need an activation function at all?

Answer (score 6):

The activation function is a *non-linear* function between inputs and outputs of layers in  neural network. If you didn't have such a function, it would be mathematically impossible for a multiple-layer NN to learn a function that isn't already possible for a one-layer NN (informally, because chaining linear systems together still leaves you with a linear system that is no more powerful, just more expensive to compute).

The important thing about the activation function is that it

- has to be nonlinear (see above)
- has to be differentiable (so that the training algorithms that make NN systems worthwhile will actually work)

(I suspect that it also has to be monotonic, but I'm not able to find a reference right now.)

In general, it's much more important that a nonlinear function is present *at all* than what function exactly is used.

Comment: okay so is the purpose of having any activation function atol is to squish out linear output between -1 nd 1 using functions like sigmoid and relu

Comment: Squishing does happen but I would say that it is more to threshold the output. It is helpful to think of an analogy of a biological neuron. A biological neuron would receive inputs from neighboring neurons, and once they reach a certain threshold it would fire an action potential. That "threshold" is determined by your activation function.